# Как сделать рандомное появление объекта в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я только начала изучать Unity и решила сделать что то типа мини игры. Мне нужно чтобы объекты появлялись в рандомных местах по всему экрану. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Про это достаточно легко найти информацию самому в интернете.

`Instantiate ( Object, new Vector2(Random.Range(- 10f, 10f) , new Vector2(Random.Range(- 10f, 10f) , Quaternion,identity);`

Эта функция создаёт объект. Первый параметр - название объекта, который вы хотите создать, второй и третий - это позиция по х и y, и последний - это вращение. В данном случае я указал, что вращать не нужно. В данном примере объект создастся рандомно в кординатах от -10 до 10 по х и y. Эти значение уже можете менять. Если надо, что б создавалось постоянно, используйте корутину.